# undefined is not an object (evaluating RNDeviceinfo.getMacAddress) Expo React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

when I'm trying to print my device mac address with the help of react-navtive-device-info.

```
"DeviceInfo.getMACAddress();"
```

it shows an error like :

> "undefined is not an object (evaluating RNDeviceinfo.getMacAddress)"

### homescreen.js

```
  import React from 'react';
  import {
  Image,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  StatusBar,
  Dimensions,
  LayoutAnimation,
  Alert,
  Linking,
} from 'react-native';
 import { WebBrowser } from 'expo';
 import { BarCodeScanner, Permissions } from 'expo';
 import { MonoText } from '../components/StyledText';

import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
```

[please see this image for the linked library to the native modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqH2g.png)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have not properly linked your library to the native modules.
You should follow the manual approach if you have used `react-native link react-native-device-info` and didn't work. 
Refer [this](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info#linking) to proceed for manual linking

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqH2g.png please see this : i already linked libraries to the native modules

Comment: Did you cross check with the android folder if it has valid linking entries for the library being linked ?

Comment: Yes, 
  public List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        // Add your own packages here!
        // TODO: add native modules!

        // Needed for `react-native link`
            new MainReactPackage(),
            new RNCameraPackage(),
            new RNDeviceInfo()
    );
  }

Comment: I looked at the MainActivity - rnpm added those lines automatically.

Comment: It should go to MainApplication.java  I believe

Comment: Sorry its in MainApplication